# LARGE & SMALL from ARRAY by MATCH

Tags: arrays, excel, match

Straight to the question.

I want to filter **K** values by **X** matching **Z**. From filtered values of **K** find LARGE & SMALL of coresponding **Y**.

So if **X=10** than find large and small of value **Y=1600** from list of values **K** with index **Z=10**. **LARGE=1500 & SMALL=2000**

```
X   Y
5   3000
5   3200
5   2800
10  1600
10  2900
10  3500
15  1800
15  4500

Z   K
5   1000
5   2000
5   3000
5   4000
10  1000
10  1500
10  2000
10  3000
10  3500
10  5000
15  1000
15  1500
15  2500
15  3000
15  4000
15  5500
```

[TABLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJCHQ.png)

I cannot figure out how to filter array of K with X=Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Large:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$G$3:$G$29/(($F$3:$F$29=A3)*($G$3:$G$29<=B3)),1)
```

For Small

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G$3:$G$29/(($F$3:$F$29=A3)*($G$3:$G$29>=B3)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: is there any chance to get it faster? if I use this script for **200+** lines for **X** and **Y,  it takes significantly longer**.

Comment: 1. make sure you are only referencing the data set and not using full column references. 2. If you are using Office 365 Excel, look into MAXIFS().  3.  If neither of those work then vba could speed it up.